Taxicab geometry and Pythagoras theorem
In an attempt to find a version of the Pythagorean theorem in the Taxicab geometry, I found that this would be

Let $a, b$ and $c$ be the lengths (in Taxicab geometry) of the sides of a right triangle in $A$, where $a$ is the length of the hypotenuse. Thus, $a=b+c-2\times d$ where $d$ is the distance between $A$ and $D$, as shown in the figure.


Is this version correct?
Note that the case where $D$ coincides with $A$, i.e. $d=0$ turns this version of the theorem into simply $a=b+c$.

The relation $a=b+c-2d$ holds even without a right angle at $A$. (Eg, moving $C$ upward one unit increases both (taxicab) distances $a$ and $b$ by $1$. These changes cancel in the relation, but the angle at $A$ is different.)

@Blue In other words, with this version you can't say that if it's valid then the triangle is right-angled, as is the case with the reciprocal of the Pythagorean theorem.
But if the triangle is right-angled, is the relationship always valid? I think so. And, by the way, is it possible to have a version that allows the reciprocal to be valid as well?

The relation $a=b+c-2d$ holds for any triangle in that general configuration (with $A$ vertically between $B$ & $C$, and $C$ horizontally between $A$ & $C$). It's a neat fact, but it's not "Pythagorean" because right-angled-ness never figures into it. But, then, it's not entirely clear to me what a "right-angled triangle" is in taxicab geometry. Defining the measures of angles can be tricky; see, for instance, this discussion (via oregonstate.edu) by Thompson and Dray. ... Good luck with your investigations!

In the Klein disk model of hyperbolic geometry there is a definition of right angle, just not the one you expect. That’s a reason other models are more popular.

What do you mean by right triangle? The usual definition is based on the usual metric...

From Taxicab Versions of Some Euclidean Theorems (via researchgate.net), by Rüstem Kaya and Harun Barış Çolakoğlu (2006), Section 3 "A Taxicab Version of the Pythagorean Theorem":

Theorem 3. Let $a$ denote the length of the hypotenuse, $b$ and $c$ denote the lengths of legs of triangle $ABC$ with right angle $A$ in the taxicab plane. Then
$$a = \begin{cases}
b+c-2\gamma, &\text{If there exists only one base line through the vertex $A$} \\
b+c, &\text{If there exist two base lines through vertex $A$}
\end{cases}$$
where $\gamma = d_T(A,H)$, and $H=$ The point of orthogonal projection of $B$ or $C$ to the base segment through $A$.



This is correct? I'm not sure...

Please don't add images as text, it's impossible to perform a search in there.

Interesting that this text also offers your formula as a Pythagorean analogue, but my earlier observation (for the "one base line" aspect) stands: The formula has nothing to do with the right-angled-ness of the triangle. (Again, moving $C$ vertically doesn't affect the calculation, despite spoiling the right angle.) So, I'm not sure why the author would present the result this way. What's the source of this passage?

We consider Taxicab Pythagorean Theorem in 2-dimensional l1 normed space.
Let $A(x,y)$ be a point with coordinates, say, $x>0$ and $y>0$. We consider the rectangle $\text{Rect}(A)$ defined by the 4 points: the origin $O(0,0), B(x,0), C(0,y)$ and $A(x,y)$.
Let $P(x_1,y_1)$ be any point in the $\text{Rect}(A)$. Then the triangle formed by the 3 points $A, O$ and $P$ satisfy Taxicab Pythagorean Theorem; that is,
$$\text{TaxiDist}(O,A)=\text{TaxiDist}(O,P)+\text{TaxiDist}(P,A).$$
For further details see:   https://arxiv.org/abs/2410.15231
